# "Run-time error '1004': No current record." How to access the data in the DAO.Recordset and how to use "WHERE" clause?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

1.I got "Run-time error '1004': No current record."
I tried  !Customers.Address
I tried .Fields(5)
I also tried ![Customers.Address]
But none of them works.
Before trying to access the data, I print out the data.
It was successful and I printed out what I expected, the address of companies for the quotation.

2.I am trying to make one quotation at a time, and the using the input quotation no.. So I added a "WHERE" clause in the code(it has been commented out)
However, it doesn't work.

Here's the code(I keep having formatting problem to copy my code. So I used images):

[image]

[image]

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SQL As String
Dim rsl As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue

'user input for the quotation no.
Message = "Plz Enter Quotation No"    ' Set prompt.
Title = "InputBox Demo"    ' Set title.
Default = "SHA-202-0001"    ' Set default.
' Display message, title, and default value.
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)

 'Show user work is being performed
DoCmd.Hourglass (True)

'******************************************************
'                   RETRIEVE DATA
'******************************************************
'SQL statement to retrieve Article_No from Quotation_Detail table
'SQL = "SELECT Article_No AS [Article No]" & _
'"FROM Quotation_Detail " & _
'"ORDER BY Article_No "
'SQL statement to retrieve Short Name, Company, Person, Telefone, USCI Num from Customers Table and Quotation No,
'Buyer, Revision, Info, Article_No, QUantity, Matchcode and RMB_price from Quotation Query 1
SQL = "SELECT Customers.[Short Name], Customers.Company, Customers.Person, Customers.Telefone, Customers.[E-Mail]," & _
"Customers.Address , Customers.City, Customers.Postcode, Customers.Province, Customers.[USCI Num]," & _
"[Quotation Query1].Buyer , [Quotation Query1].[Our Reference]," & _
"[Quotation Query1].[Quotation Date] , [Quotation Query1].Revision, [Quotation Query1].Info," & _
"[Quotation Query1].Article_No , [Quotation Query1].Quantity, [Quotation Query1].Matchcode," & _
"[Quotation Query1].RMB_price , [Quotation Query Query].[Quotation No], [Quotation Query Query].[Sum Of total]" '& _
"FROM (Customers INNER JOIN ([Quotation Query Query] INNER JOIN Quotation ON [Quotation Query Query].[Quotation No] = Quotation.[Quotation No]) ON Customers.[Short Name] = Quotation.[Buyer]) INNER JOIN [Quotation Query1] ON Customers.[Short Name] = [Quotation Query1].[Buyer]" & _
'"WHERE [Quotation Query Query].[Quotation No] = Myvalue"
'To select only one quotation with the quotation no. to make the quotation but failed with WHERE clause

'Execute query and populate recordset
Set rsl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

'If no data, don't bother opening Excel, just quit
If rsl.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No data selected for export", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No data exported"
    GoTo SubExit
End If

'Loop each row to print data in rsl(0) to test what's in the rsl
'rsl(0) is the short name
'rsl(1) is the company name
' Contrl G to see what have been printed
Do While Not rsl.EOF
    Debug.Print rsl(5)
    rsl.MoveNext
Loop

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Cindy\Desktop\Quotation_Master.xlsx")
appExcel.Visible = True
Set xlSheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 With xlSheet
    .Name = "Quotation"
    .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Cells.Font.Size = 11


    'build quotation info
    .Range("C16").Value = MyValue
    .Range("A6").Value = rsl(5)
    .Range("A9").Value = rsl!Customers.Postcode
    .Range("B12").Value = rsl!Customers.Telefone
    .Range("B13").Value = rsl!Customers.[E-Mail]
    .Range("B14").Value = rsl!Customers.[USCI Num]
    .Range("F16").Value = rsl![Quotation Query1].Revision
    .Range("B17").Value = rsl![Quotation Query1].[Quotation Date]
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Instead, include the actual code in your question instead so people can copy/paste it.

Comment: Please post the code - select your code and press the toolbar button above the edit box labelled `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the importance of having the actual code and the tip for post the code.I am kinda new to the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Give a space at the end of every line.

```
SQL = "SELECT Customers.[Short Name], Customers.Company, Customers.Person, Customers.Telefone, Customers.[E-Mail]," & _
"Customers.Address , Customers.City, Customers.Postcode, Customers.Province, Customers.[USCI Num]," & _
"[Quotation Query1].Buyer , [Quotation Query1].[Our Reference]," & _
"[Quotation Query1].[Quotation Date] , [Quotation Query1].Revision, [Quotation Query1].Info," & _
"[Quotation Query1].Article_No , [Quotation Query1].Quantity, [Quotation Query1].Matchcode," & _
"[Quotation Query1].RMB_price , [Quotation Query Query].[Quotation No], [Quotation Query Query].[Sum Of total]" & _
" FROM (Customers INNER JOIN ([Quotation Query Query] INNER JOIN Quotation ON [Quotation Query Query].[Quotation No] = Quotation.[Quotation No]) ON Customers.[Short Name] = Quotation.[Buyer]) INNER JOIN [Quotation Query1] ON Customers.[Short Name] = [Quotation Query1].[Buyer] " & _
" WHERE [Quotation Query Query].[Quotation No] = '" & Myvalue & "'  "
```

There is room for errors when connecting to your sql character. If possible, it is a good idea to leave a space at the end when concatenating characters.

```
[Quotation Query Query]. [Sum Of total]FROM (Customers INNER JOIN
```

Since it is written in this way, an error occurs.

Also, since you went through EOF to debug the recordset, you never get a recordset again.
Therefore, you should either remove the debugging code or move the recordset underneath for the first time.

```
Do While Not rsl.EOF
    Debug.Print rsl(5)
    rsl.MoveNext
Loop
rsl.MoveFirst '<~~ this code needs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still doesn't work. I got Run-time error '3265': Items not found in this collection. However, I can still print rsl(5) successfully. I guess the space doesn't matter in VBA.

Comment: While You  did debuged, the recordset  go to eof.  So dont  debug. Or  after  debug recordset  movefirst.

Comment: Thank you, Dy.Lee. Now I understand the problem with my debug print loop. The cursor goes to eof. And it works now! But I tried Single quotation before and after myvalue. It now gives me Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression. I think Myvalue originally is already a string.

Comment: Thanks, Dy.Lee. You are right. Single quote is needed. My [Quotation Query1].[Quotation No] is not a string. I converted it to  a str by Str([Quotation Query1].[Quotation No]). No error but my rsl.RecordCount = 0.

Comment: After I changed to " WHERE [Quotation Query Query].[Quotation No] = '" & MyValue & "'  ", I got "Error Number:3061 = Too few parameters. Expected 1".